# after 2 days web stopped working but Tomcat still running. Restart of Tomcat fixes issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running Tomcat7 on a provisioning server (Ubuntu OS) to provision devices. Issue is http stops working after couple of more days and when i restart tomcat everything get back on normal. 
I've gathered below logs.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [main] in context with path [/web] threw exception [java.io.IOException: <p>An error occured</p>ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)] with root cause
java.io.IOException: <p>An error occured</p>ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.Output.deliverHTML(Output.java:455)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.Output.deliverResponse(Output.java:140)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.Main.doImpl(Main.java:183)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.Main.doGet(Main.java:94)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.Main.doPost(Main.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.owera.xaps.web.app.security.LoginServlet.doFilter(LoginServlet.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea / help

Comment: Sounds like a resource leak.

Answer (score 0):

Bill, you will have to analyse thread dumps and will have to go through your application code once. It seems objects are not getting GC.

But before that, to prove this analogy, you can try to double your Memory.
In your catalina.sh/catalina.bat *(depending on OS)* please try to modify your **-Xmx**, **-Xms** and **-XX:MaxPermSize** and observe if it has any impact on your server uptime.

Comment: I am currently using -Xmx2048m for running application. One more thing i observe, i got alot of below errors in syslog when it stops working.


ProvMsg: PP:XXXX, ST:ERROR, PO:CONFIG, EV:2, PM:REGULAR, ER:CLIENT, EM:TR-XXXX session was aborted - most probably because the client did not respond

Comment: What do you mean by client, didn't respond? Are you opening two way communication b/w server and client?